Cannot upload file with ajax and asp.net webservice in shared hosting
I have created an application to upload files to a folder using ajax request and asp.net webservice.asmx. It's working fine in my local system with IIS. But when I hosted it in my Mochahost shared hosting uploading function not working.
My ajax function is:
function FileUpload(MasterID) {
var formData = new FormData();
var fileUpload = $('#fileupload2').get(0);
var files = fileUpload.files;
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    formData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);        
}
formData.append('MasterID', MasterID);
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../../Webservices/Payment.asmx/UploadFile",
    data: formData,
    success: function (data) {

    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert('error' + data)
    },
    async: false,
    contentType:false,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    
});
function OnSuccess(data) {
    console.log(data);
}

}
my webservice function is:
[WebMethod]
public string UploadFile()
{
    try
    {
        var MasterID = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["MasterID"];
        HttpFileCollection Files = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
        string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Upload/");
        for (int i = 0; i < Files.Count; i++)
        {
            HttpPostedFile File = Files[i];
            string fileName = Regex.Replace(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(File.FileName) + Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), @"\s+", "");
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(File.FileName);

            File.SaveAs(Path.Combine(path, String.Concat(fileName, extension)));
            object[,] ParamArray;
            ParamArray = new object[,] {    
                                        {"@AccMasterID", MasterID },
                                        {"@FileName", fileName+extension }
                                       };
            
            string res = Convert.ToString(DB.ExecuteScalar_SP("[UpdateFileNameAccTransactionMaster]", ParamArray));
            return res;
        }
        return "nofile";    
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "error";
    }
}

When I debugged the code in my online server, the problem is when I use contentType: false server is showing following error:
    [InvalidOperationException]: Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in &#39;/UploadFile&#39;.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.CoreGetHandler(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String verb, String url, String filePath)
   at System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String url, String pathTranslated)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

But without contentType:false, uploading does not work. The same code is working fine in my system with contentType:false.
